# Having trouble deleting multiple queries (PHP, MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql, http, form

I'm having trouble making WHERE IN query work, I was only able to make it work as a foreach loop.

My payload looks like this:

```
sku[]: BOOK0002
sku[]: BOOK0003
```

My API file code is as follows:

```
    public function deleteProduct($prdt_sku)
    {
        try {
            $this->db->query("DELETE FROM products WHERE product_sku IN :sku");
            $this->db->bind(":sku", $prdt_sku);

            if ($this->db->execute()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Throwable $e) {
            echo 'Error deleting product from database. Reirecting...';
            header("HTTP/1.1 406 Error deleting product from database");
            header("refresh:3;url=https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/add-product");
        }
    }
```

My actual form destination:

```
$response = array();

if (isset($_POST['sku'])) {

     foreach ($sku as $deletables) {
         $result = $api->deleteProduct($deletables);
     }

    if ($result) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
        header("Location: https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/add-product");
        exit();
    } else {
        header("HTTP/1.1 406 Error deleting product");
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 499 Required parameters missing");
    echo 'Please select one or more of the checkboxes. Reirecting...';
    header("refresh:3;url=https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/");
}
```

I need to use the WHERE IN clause so I can have only one query per form & reduce the unnecessary amount of queries I'm using right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

*Update*
My PDO:

````
<?php

class Database
{
    private $host = DB_SERVER;
    private $user = DB_USERNAME;
    private $pass = DB_PASSWORD;
    private $dbname = DB_NAME;

    private $dbh;
    private $stmt;
    private $error;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        );

        try {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            echo $this->error;
        }
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function bind($param, $value, $type = null)
    {
        if (is_null($type)) {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                    break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                    break;
                default:
                    $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            }
        }

        $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultSet()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function single()
    {
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Does this work as expected: `$this->db->query("DELETE FROM products WHERE product_sku IN :sku");`? Also, in the second snippet: `$sku` is not declared so I would expect `foreach ($sku as $deletables) {` to throw an exception...

Comment: Because `foreach ($sku as $deletables) { $result = $api->deleteProduct($deletables); }` keeps overwriting the boolean value, your `if ($result)` will only be respecting the last iteration's value.  Do you want to be more accurately checking if the DELETE query affected any rows? Do you need an `exit()` in your `catch()` block?  Why are there `header()`s after `echo`s in your scripts?  Does this code work as intended???

Comment: This code works as intended unfortunately (I’m a noob in PHP) if you have any idea how I can replace the foreach in the code with just one query your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can't "bind" anything after `IN`.  Binding only generates a string; `IN` does not want a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this shows [the limitations of creating a PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper). It makes it difficult to get rid of the `foreach` loop. Your wrapper is quite simple though, so I'll ignore it for now and use plain PDO.

The problem here is that you need a variable amount of placeholders in your query depending on how many entries there are in `$prdt_sku`. I solved this by using `?` placeholders, like this:

```
public function deleteProducts(PDO $pdoHandle, array $products_sku)
{
    try {
        // put the right amount of placeholders in the query
        $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_sku IN (" . 
                  trim(str_repeat(",?", count($products_sku)), ",") . ")";
        $statement = $pdoHandle->prepare($query);
        return $statement->execute($products_sku);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        echo 'Error deleting products from database. Redirecting...';
        header("HTTP/1.1 406 Error deleting product from database");
        header("refresh:3;url=https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/add-product");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Note that this function now deletes multiple products. Here the assumption is that your "payload" is:

`$products_sku = ["BOOK0002", "BOOK0003"];`

It is actually not so difficult to use your wrapper for this. All that is needed is a small change to your `execute()` method. Like this:

```
public function execute($parameters = null)
{
    return $this->stmt->execute($parameters);
}
```

Then the `deleteProducts()` method can become this:

```
public function deleteProducts(array $products_sku)
{
    try {
        // put the right amount of placeholders in the query
        $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_sku IN (" . 
                  trim(str_repeat(",?", count($products_sku)), ",") . ")";
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $this->db->execute($products_sku);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        echo 'Error deleting product from database. Reirecting...';
        header("HTTP/1.1 406 Error deleting product from database");
        header("refresh:3;url=https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/add-product");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Some notes:

I really don't like variable names like `$prdt_sku`. Try to pronounce that! Most people would know what a "sku" is, so that's an acceptable abbreviation, but why do you use "prdt"? It must stand for "product", but would `$product_sku` be so bad? Please *don't abbreviate unnecessarily*. It's not faster, you don't safe memory space, all you do is make your code harder to read. Do you want that?

I cringe a bit at the way you handle the exception. You print an error and then jump out of the method and load another URL after 3 seconds. That's quite inflexible. You can never handle this exception in any other way. The worst thing is that you don't actually `die` or `exit` after the headers. That means code execution continues as if nothing happened. The method also doesn't return anything. Why not do:

```
public function deleteProducts(array $products_sku)
{
    try {
        // put the right amount of placeholders in the query
        $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_sku IN (" . 
                  trim(str_repeat(",?", count($products_sku)), ",") . ")";
        $this->db->query($query);
        return $this->db->execute($products_sku);
    } catch (Throwable $e) {
        <.... store reason of exception ....>
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then the calling code can still decide what to do with any failures. I would also store the reason for the exception somewhere in the class, so you can actually tell what happened. Note that the PDO statement does something similar with [PDOStatement::errorInfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php).

Comment: It completely broke mate :(

Comment: @Metwesh I'm sorry about that. Do I need to contact my insurance?

Comment: Hahahahaha no that won't be necessary. Thanks a lot for the effort tho :)

Comment: Why return HTTP 406 status in this case?

Comment: @Kate: That's not actually what is returned, because of the page refresh header. It returns a 302. See the other answer by Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ♦ to this question. I only used it because it was in the original code of the question. In my final code proposal it is absent.

Answer (score 1):

For the case when the POST data does not contain `sku`, the following code occurs:

> ```
> header("HTTP/1.1 499 Required parameters missing");
> echo 'Please select one or more of the checkboxes. Reirecting...';
> header("refresh:3;url=https://metwesh.github.io/scandiweb-product-page/");
> ```

HTTP Status code 499 is:

> A non-standard status code introduced by [nginx](https://nginx.org/) for the case when a client closes the connection while nginx is processing the request.
> <sup>[1](https://httpstatuses.com/499)</sup>

A more appropriate status code for such a case would be [400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) or [422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422).

Also note the documentation for [`header()`](https://php.net/header) states:

> The second special case is the "Location:" header. Not only does it send this header back to the browser, but it also returns a `REDIRECT` (302) status code to the browser unless the 201 or a 3xx status code has already been set.
> <sup>[2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-parameters)</sup>

Thus the status code other than 201 or 3xx likely isn't being respected.

Also, hopefully the code is running on PHP 5.4 (and given [LTS](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) - hopefully it is running on PHP 7.4 or later) and presuming this, consider using [`http_response_code()`](https://php.net/http_response_code) instead of using `header()` to set the status code. For more context on this, refer to answers to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25305961/1575353).